# .dynamicType is deprecated. Use 'type(of ...)' instead

Tags: swift, xcode

I've just updated to Xcode 8 and iOS 10 (using legacy Swift Language Version).

Trying to compile again my project has been an agony, even still using the old Swift syntax. This time one of my functions uses `NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)` but now appears that `.dynamicType` is deprecated and Xcode doesn't even want to compile it.

His suggestion is to use `type(of: self)` but that fails as well. Anyone knows the solution? Thanks.

Comment: `NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)` compiles fine for me in Swift 2.3, are you sure "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" is set to "Yes"? You could always try cleaning your build folder.

Comment: Yes, it's set and I can see the effect because the number of syntax errors decreases from 30 to 1. My opinion is that this error is related to the new UIKit framework updated in the new iOS 10 SDK, that's why when I updated to Xcode 8 it appeared even activating the legacy Swift syntax.

Comment: Never mind my last statement, UIKit is still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dfri answer works perfectly for Swift 3.

Regarding Swift 2.3, my solution was to clean Xcode (Command+Option+Shift+K) and delete everything in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. The problem doesn't disappear instantly but after some time it will stop giving that error.

Maybe it's a bug, after all we are in 8.0. I hope it gets fixed in next releases.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: @sgonzalez His answer works for Swift 3. I was using legacy Swift (2).

Answer (score 35):

*(The below holds for Swift 3; not legacy Swift Language Version (2.3), however, so it doesn't answer the OP's question, but could be valuable for Swift 3 users, nonetheless)*

As noted in your question, `dynamicType` is now (Swift 3) deprecated in favour of `type(of:)`. In addition:

- `NSBundle` has been renamed to `Bundle`.
- The `init(forClass:)` initializer of `Bundle` has been renamed to `init(for:)`.

Taking these changes into account, For Swift 3 you initialize (or fetch an existing instance associated with the specific class) your `Bundle` object in the following manner:

```
class Foo {
    func bar() -> () {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is using the legacy Swift version, aka Swift 2.3 – so AFAIK his current code should be valid

Comment: No problem, I thought the same at first glance!

Comment: What's `type(of: self)` ? Where does it come from? Autocomplete doesn't  suggest me such code. Also, looking at documentation can't seem to find anything related to `type(of: )`. But copy pasting the exact same code doesn't yield any errors. Maybe I should restart Xcode.

Comment: @Andrej See the [release notes for Xcode 8](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html): _"The `dynamicType` keyword has been removed from Swift. In its place a new primitive function `type(of:)` has been added to the language. Existing code that uses the `.dynamicType` member to retrieve the type of an expression should migrate to this new primitive."_. If you attempt to use `dynamicType` in Swift 3/Xcode 8, you should be promted with similar information (-> replace with `type(of:)`).